# How to flush DNS cache in Firefox

Tags: networking, firefox, dns, browser-cache

Strange issue... whenever I try to access http://docs.python.org/ from Firefox on Win 7, I get redirected to http://docs.python.org/old_dns.txt which says:

> You need to update your DNS records for docs.python.org. This is the old docs server.

My first thought was to do a `ipconfig /flushdns`, but that didn't fix the problem.

I also determined that the it wasn't a cache at my local network nor ISP level... (both returns 199.27.76.175)

```
C:\>nslookup docs.python.org.
Server:  [INSTITUTION AD DNS SERVER - REMOVED]
Address:  [REMOVED]

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    c.global-ssl.fastly.net
Address:  199.27.76.175
Aliases:  docs.python.org


C:\>nslookup docs.python.org. 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    c.global-ssl.fastly.net
Address:  199.27.76.175
Aliases:  docs.python.org
```

I have the *Flagfox* extension installed and it's showing `199.27.76.175` as the address as well.

`Ctrl-F5` to refresh did not work either.

The weirdest thing is when I accessed the same address in Chrome, it worked (redirected me to https://docs.python.org/3/)

Having known this, I tried https://docs.python.org/ (notice the httpS) in Firefox, and it worked as well! (Redirected to https://docs.python.org/3/).

What's up with this?! How can I fix this?

Since Chrome works and the IP is obviously the same as Google's DNS server, I assume this is caused by a Firefox internal DNS cache and the Flagfox address displayed is resolved separately and not the actual address used to contact the server.

Comment: You can modify how firefox caches using about:config and the network.dnsCacheExpiration key. Setting it to 0 disables cache altogether. If you wait longer than the value in seconds specified in that key, the query will not use a cached result from firefox (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration)

Answer (score 2):

I have learned that you must press `Control+F5` a few times on Firefox for it to have any effect.

Btw there's also a [DNS Flusher addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dns-flusher/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you (or your company) perhaps using a proxy that might have cached the DNS record? Even though you have flushed your local DNS cache, the proxy might need to flush it's DNS cache too.